# vtkLegendBoxActor is not supportting to set text font size

Tags: python, vtk

I am using vtkLegendBoxActor to show legends in a plot. However, I am unable to control the font size of text in the legend.
I have tried the following:

```
legendActor=vtkLegendBoxActor()
textProp=vtkTextProperty()
textProp.SetFontSize(3)
textProp.SetVerticalJustificationToCentered()
legendActor.SetEntryTextProperty(textProp)
```

However, this seems not set the font size of the text. It still appears the default size of 12. I have checked the font size after setting the property as:

```
legendActor.GetEntryTextProperty().GetFontSize()
```

Which returns 3. Please help me to fix the issue.

Thank you.